# Mysql says it expects a semicolon when there is one

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a loop in SQL, but this code :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
END;
```

Gives the error "Statement is incomplete, expecting ';'" on the DECLARE line. What am I doing wrong ? I'm on MySQL 8.

Comment: Are you setting delimiters? What UI are you using (if any) ? Are you doing this from command line? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: Try `DELIMITER //` before your script and replace the final `;` with `//`, then `DELIMITER ;` after

Comment: The error message does not come from mysql, it would raise a syntax error message in such case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it like this using DELIMITER [(according to official examples of MySQL)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html)

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE doiterate(p1 INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE count INT DEFAULT 0;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```